# How to replace part of a mesh with another part

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, vertex-groups

I would like to make both eyes exactly the same (one is slightly thinner than the other), how would I take the vertices from one and replace them with vertices from the other? The head is a sphere and this is a very dense mesh. Using Blender 2.82 on Mac OSX 10.13.6.[image]
[image]

Comment: You might need to just manually resize it. Not sure if it's possible to make that kind of change otherwise considering the insane topology.

Comment: For a mesh like that, you are using way too many polygons. Retopologizing would help you manage projects like what you want much better. Work with simpler shapes, to get the overall design of your character first, and only then add detail, and you will find that you don't need that dense a mesh.

Comment: Was hoping it might be possible to exchange vertex group, similar to exchanging object data.

Comment: it could have been possible with Mesh > Symmetrize but your object is not aligned with any axis.